# UWPToolkit - What is a ItemTemplate and how do I make one for my AdaptiveGrid?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

Im currently trying to use the `AdaptiveGrid` in the toolkit to display Some images that then can be clicked on to lead to pages, I think this `ItemTemplate` is what provides the images in the example. Is this the same as any `DataTemplate`? I cant find any information online about these or docs.

```
<Controls:AdaptiveGridView Name="AdaptiveGridViewControl"
                                   OneRowModeEnabled="False"
                                   ItemHeight="200"
                                   DesiredWidth="300"
                                   SelectionMode="Single"
                                   IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                                   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PhotosTemplate}"/>
```

I've tried the following, I get no errors but nothing shows up when I run it locally except the command bar:

Mainpage.xaml:

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MobileAppProject"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:viewModels="using:ViewModels"
    xmlns:Controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    x:Class="MobileAppProject.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d">


    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="AdaptTemplate">
            <Grid
                Background="White"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="1">
                <Image
                    Source="{Binding Image}"
                    Stretch="UniformToFill"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="12,10,12,12">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>



                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,10"/>

                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Controls:AdaptiveGridView Name="AdaptiveGridViewControl"
                                   OneRowModeEnabled="False"
                                   ItemHeight="200"
                                   DesiredWidth="300"
                                   SelectionMode="Single"
                                   IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                                   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AdaptTemplate}"/>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,24,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}">

                        <CommandBar x:Name="cmdbar" 
                                    IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=isopentoggle, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    IsSticky="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=isstickytoggle, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    ClosedDisplayMode="{Binding SelectedItem.Content, ElementName=combobox}">
                            <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
                                <AppBarButton Label="Menu Item 1"/>
                                <AppBarButton Label="Menu Item 2"/>
                                <AppBarButton Label="Menu Item 3"/>
                                <AppBarButton Label="Menu Item 4"/>
                            </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
                            <AppBarButton Icon="Accept" Label="Accept"/>
                            <AppBarToggleButton Icon="Contact" Label="Contact"/>
                        </CommandBar>
                        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="Assets/storeLogo-sdk.png" Stretch="None"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>

                <!-- Status Block for providing messages to the user.  Use the
             NotifyUser() method to populate the message -->
                <TextBlock x:Name="StatusBlock" Grid.Row="2" Margin="12, 10, 12, 10" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Mainpage.xaml.cs:

```
private ObservableCollection<AdaptItem> picItems_;

        private ObservableCollection<AdaptItem> PicItems
        {
            get
            {
                return picItems_;
            }
            set
            {
                picItems_ = value;
            }

        }
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            picItems_ = AdaptItem.AdaptList();
            this.DataContext = PicItems;
        }
```

AdaptTemplate.cs for filling the AdaptGrid:

```
 public class AdaptItem
    {
        public String Image
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<AdaptItem> AdaptList()
    {
        ObservableCollection<AdaptItem> pics = new ObservableCollection<AdaptItem>()
        {
            new AdaptItem
            {
                Image = "Assets/01.jpg"
            },
            new AdaptItem
            {
                Image = "Assets/02.jpg"
            },
            new AdaptItem
            {
                Image = "Assets/03.jpg"
            },
            new AdaptItem
            {
                Image = "Assets/04.jpg"
            },
            new AdaptItem
            {
                Image = "Assets/05.jpg"
            }
        };

        return pics;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check how the template is used in the UWP Toolkit sample app or in the [sample code on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/SamplePages/AdaptiveGridView/AdaptiveGridViewPage.xaml):

```
<Controls:AdaptiveGridView Name="AdaptiveGridViewControl"
                                   OneRowModeEnabled="False"
                                   ItemHeight="200"
                                   DesiredWidth="300"
                                   SelectionMode="Single"
                                   IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                                   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PhotosTemplate}">
   <Controls:AdaptiveGridView.Resources>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="PhotosTemplate">
        <Grid
            Background="White"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="1">
            <Image
                Source="{Binding Thumbnail}"
                Stretch="UniformToFill"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
   </Controls:AdaptiveGridView.Resources>
</Controls:AdaptiveGridView>
```

In short - yes, the `ItemTemplate` works the same way as any other `DataTemplate`.

Comment: I've followed the GitHub sample and tried to create a DataTemplate to use as the source for the images but nothing appears when I run it, Ive updated the post can you see what Im doing wrong?

Comment: You are setting the `DataContext` but you are not connecting the data source of the Grid view. You have to add `ItemsSource={Binding}` to the `AdaptiveGridView` element.